# gitolite disallow access for directory on master branch but not on user branch

Tags: git, gitolite, gitlab

Consider the following repo:

REPO/src/A/

REPO/src/B/

Is it possible by having only 1 repo to implement the following restrictions?

1. On master branch, allow full access to maintainers role
2. On master branch, disallow access to A but allow for B to contributors role.
3. On personal branches, allow full access to A and B to creators.

Comment: Note: the VREF by name might be, in your case: `VREF/NAME/src/A` instead of `VREF/NAME/A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Gitolite V3 [or 'g3'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html) and its [VREF](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html), it should be possible to implement those restrictions.

But the access you can manage is only for write-access.
If a user can clone a repo, he/she will have read-access to *all* the repo (as mentioned in "[gitolite: allow to change only selelected files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204881/gitolite-allow-to-change-only-selelected-files/3205192#3205192)").
If you really want to limit read-access, you might try [gitolite '`partial-copy`'](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/non-core.html#partial-copy).

Few notes:

- VREF can be used for [restricting pushes by dir/file name](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME).
- I use here the notion of **[role](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/wild.html)**, not group of users: you need to [set the permission separately](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/user.html#perms) for said users.
- Personnal branches are [described here](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/special.html#pers).

An [access rule](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/rules.html) is like:

```
<permission> <zero or more refexes> = <one or more users/user groups>
```

**`<zero or more refexes>`** means your can combines refexes

That would give something like (not tested):

```
repo REPO
        RW+  master                     =   MAINTAINER
        -    master         VREF/NAME/A =   CONTRIBUTOR
        RW   master         VREF/NAME/B =   CONTRIBUTOR
        RW   personal/USER/ VREF/NAME/A =   CREATOR
        RW   personal/USER/ VREF/NAME/B =   CREATOR
```

Comment: Hey, i don't care about read access. I ll give a go with your suggested setup and come back with feedback.

Comment: @Konstantinos Excellent. Make sure you have gitolite V3 installed within your GitLab setup. And try it outside of gitlab, with direct git command through ssh.

Comment: @VonC, but aren’t combined refexes ORed and not ANDed?

Comment: @MichalRus not exactly: it follows a principle of rule accumulation: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf.html#rule-accumulation

Answer (score 0):

```
repo REPO
    - master VREF/NAME/src/A = @contributors
    RW+ master = @maintainers @contributors
    RW+ personal/ = @creators
```