# Is it possible to specify a rule for a file for a specific branch?

Tags: gitolite

I have a GIT repository `foo` with 2 branches: `branch1` and `branch2`. I want to set up a gitolite rule that denies pushing modifications for `this` file only for `branch1` for `bar` user. This is what I've tried so far:

```
repo foo
    - branch1/this = bar

repo foo
    - branch1/NAME/this = bar

repo foo
    - branch1 /NAME/this = bar
```

I don't even know if this is possible with gitolite.

Any help very much welcome. Thanks in advance.

---

*EDIT*: I tried this 2 configurations [as suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002042/898478). The following:

```
-  branch1 VREF/NAME/this = bar
RW branch2 VREF/NAME/this = @all
```

rejects both branches

```
remote: FATAL: W VREF/NAME/this testing bar DENIED by VREF/NAME/this
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/branch2
remote: FATAL: W VREF/NAME/this testing bar DENIED by VREF/NAME/this
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/branch1
To debian:testing.git
 ! [remote rejected] branch2 -> branch2 (hook declined)
 ! [remote rejected] branch1 -> branch1 (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'debian:testing.git'
```

While the following

```
RW branch2 VREF/NAME/this = @all
-  branch1 VREF/NAME/this = bar
```

allows both branches to be pushed

```
To debian:testing.git
   f6bc01d..09b63ab  branch2 -> branch2
   7a868cf..09bcb63  branch1 -> branch1
```

---

Using the same branch (`branch1`)

```
RW branch1 VREF/NAME/this = @all
-  branch1 VREF/NAME/this = bar

To debian:testing.git
   9c50fc4..02f350d  branch1 -> branch1

-  branch1 VREF/NAME/this = bar
RW branch1 VREF/NAME/this = @all

remote: FATAL: W VREF/NAME/this testing bar DENIED by VREF/NAME/this
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/branch1
To debian:testing.git
 ! [remote rejected] branch1 -> branch1 (hook declined)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
repo foo
    - branch1 VREF/NAME/this = bar
```

I used a similar [VREF-based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309) rule for "[gitolite disallow access for directory on master branch but not on user branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11900083/6309)".
'`VREF/...`' is the important part ('`NAME`' alone won't work, '`VREF/NAME`' will)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I just saw your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899405/gitolite-disallow-access-for-directory-on-master-branch-but-not-on-user-branch) but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: `remote: FATAL: W VREF/NAME/this foo bar DENIED by VREF/NAME/this
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/branch2`

Comment: @m0skit0 Try to add a success rule after the deny rule: `RW branch2 VREF/NAME/this = @all`

Comment: @m0skit0 if that doesn't work, try the same success rule *before* the deny rule. Check also that your '`branch2`' local branch is pushed to a '`branch2`' upstream branch (`git branch -vvv`)

Comment: Yes, it's pushed to remote: `branch2 f6bc01d [origin/branch2] Testing`. I added `RW+ branch1 VREF/NAME/this = bar` before the deny. Still the same.

Comment: @m0skit0 why not add the success rule I mentioned earlier? (success rule on branch2)

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I added `RW branch2 VREF/NAME/this = @all` and kept previous deny rule. I can push the file to both branches now. The rule looks like applying to all branches, no matter which one I specify.

Comment: @m0skit0 and what if you reverse the order between the two rules?

Comment: Rejected in both branches.

Comment: @m0skit0 can you edit your question with those two configs, and their result?

Comment: @m0skit0 Could you try a success rule **for the same branch**? `RW branch1 VREF/NAME/this = @all` (before or after the deny rule for the same branch `branch1`)

Comment: Updated the question with it