# How can you restrict Gitolite VREF restrictions to only one branch?

Tags: gitolite

Nobody should be able to write to the profiles/recruiter directory in the repository, except for a sync user that pushes changes there:

```
repo    test
    RW                                = @contributors gitsync
    RW  VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/ = gitsync
    -   VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/ = @all
```

This works so far. Now I only want to have that restriction on the master branch, so that contributors can push any stuff to feature branches. But this does not work:

```
repo    test
    RW                                       = @contributors gitsync
    RW  master VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/ = gitsync
    -   master VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/ = @all
```

Even if I add master to the first rule it does not work:

```
repo    test
        RW                                      = @contributors
        RW  master                              = @contributors
        RW  master VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/ = klausi
        -   master VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/ = klausi_test
```

The klausi_test user is then not allowed to push stuff in the profiles/recruiter directory to some foobar branch.

I also tried [gitolite disallow access for directory on master branch but not on user branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899405/gitolite-disallow-access-for-directory-on-master-branch-but-not-on-user-branch) , but that also did not work. Any hints?

Comment: But in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11900083/6309, I added also `master` to the first rule. `RW master = @contributors gitsync`. Can you try and add `master` in that first rule?

Comment: Even if I add master to the first rule it does not work.

Comment: What version of gitolite are you using?

Comment: Maybe updating to the latest would help to learn more about why the VREF isn't working, because of https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/commit/3154e46c93f8561633908e5c6b6e35003ae6c25e (I just had a closer look, this is just to add information message, so not so helpful in your case)

Comment: The access command though could help: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/3154e46c93f8561633908e5c6b6e35003ae6c25e/src/commands/access

Answer (score 1):

I had to figure out something like this recently, and I think I figured out how using the [refex-expr](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/VREF/refex-expr) feature. I believe this is a feature in 3.6.2. The following setup should work.

```
repo test
    RW                                           = @contributors gitsync
    RW  master                                   = @contributors
    RW  VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/            = @contributors
    -   master and VREF/NAME/profiles/recruiter/ = @contributors
```

Note that you need to enable the refex-expr feature in your .gitolite.rc file.