# Gitlab separate branch access to separate users

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I Configured gitlab on my localhost ubuntu. My concern is to give separate access to the repository branches.

We have 3 separate departments

- 1-Developers
- 2-Testers
- 3-Team leads

For these three departments I need separate access. Developers can only access dev branch. Testers can only access qa branch and team leads can access all the branches including the master. Once the team leads review the code then they will merge the branch to master.

Is there any option in Gitlab? Please give me a suggestion. If there are any other tools we can use other than gitlab please let me know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow per user protected branches access in GitLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348071/how-to-allow-per-user-protected-branches-access-in-gitlab)

Comment: You can only protect branches from being changed, and not from being seen. If you don't want everyone seeing the whole repo, use smaller repos.

Comment: In short, you can not set permissions based on branches. All the users who can access to your gitab repo have read permissions for all branches at least.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at Gitlab User and Roles https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html yet?